# get the form data using Cgicc

Tags: c++, cgi, form-data

```
char* fileContentLength;
int nContentLength;
fileContentLength = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");

if(fileContentLength == NULL)   
    return -1;      

nContentLength = atoi(fileContentLength);   

if(nContentLength == 0) 
    return -1;

data = (char*) malloc(nContentLength+1);

if(data == NULL)    
    return -1;

memset(data, 0, nContentLength+1);  
if(fread(data, 1, nContentLength, stdin) == 0)  
    return -1;

if(ferror(stdin))
```

This is c++ cgi code to get form data to a character array. 
After executing this code, i got the below result to the variable "data".

> f0=fname0&l0=lname0&f1=fname1&l1=lname1&f2=fname2&l2=lname2&f3=&l3=

Now i want to use cgicc to retrieve data like above in a single character array. But using cgicc i can get the value of specific element. But i want to retrieve all element values in a single character array. How can i do this using cgicc?

Comment: thats a weird C++!!! mallocing!!

Comment: I retrieved all data in a character array using the above code. But I want to use Cgicc to get the specific element data. So i declared a variable for Cgicc like below 
Cgicc formData;
If i added this code , i got program termination at if(fread(data, 1, nContentLength, stdin) == 0)  code. If i comment the above declaration means, its working fine. I don't know what is happening here when declaring a variable for cgicc.

Comment: getpostdata is an option but it returns MIME

Comment: Sorry ! i couldn't get your answer. Now what should i do to resolve my problem ? Can you explain ?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/doc/classcgicc_1_1CgiEnvironment.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late reply, but maybe it well help someone.

This may be related to a problem I experienced.  Yesterday I started working with C++ Cgi scripts for the very first time.  I discovered that declaring Cgicc multiple times in the code while submitting data with the POST method (GET works fine) caused a "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' ... what():  I/O error".  It was resolved by declaring Cgicc globally, and thus, only once in the code.